# Suppress column headings in proc report

Tags: sas

My boss would like me to create a chart and table in SAS similar to something you can produce in excel, where the data table sits below the chart. This would mean using the data on the x-axis and placing more data below it.

Desired output

> ```
>     (chart area) (Row 1) Building 1    Building 2   Building 3   Building 4 
>                  (Row 2)   333             267          234         235 
>                  (Row 3)   3232            213         3215         657
> ```

I'm not sure how to do this in proc report, where the data runs long, instead of wide. Also, the data set is long:

```
Building ID    var1     var2
Building 1      333     3232
Building 2      267     213
```

Comment: First, I think you want two PROCs. Maybe use something like Proc GChart for the chart, then use Proc Report for the data table.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

CarolinaJay's suggestion of a PROC GCHART or SGPLOT or whatnot followed by another proc is the way to go, IMO; while you could do both at once, it's a lot more work to do so.

To accomplish your specific table, I recommend PROC TABULATE; it doesn't care what direction your data goes.

```
data have;
informat buildingID $12.;
input BuildingID $    var1     var2;
datalines;
Building1      333     3232
Building2      267     213
;;;;
run;
proc tabulate data=have;
class buildingID;
var var1 var2;
tables (var1 var2)*sum=' ', buildingID=' ';
run;
```

Plop that under a plot, and you have something like this (I have no idea how to plot this so I just picked something totally at random):

```
ods _all_ close;
ods html;
data have;
informat buildingID $12.;
input BuildingID $    var1     var2;
datalines;
Building1      333     323
Building2      267     213
;;;;
run;
proc sgplot data=have;
vbar var1/response=var2 group=buildingID;
run;
title;
proc tabulate data=have;
class buildingID;
var var1 var2;
tables (var1 var2)*sum=' ', buildingID=' ';
run;
ods html close;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! I now need to get rid of the Sum column. Is there a way from suppressing this? 
My table looks like this 
percent|sum|100|100|98.2....
I want to get rid of this "sum"column.

Comment: Not sure, the ' ' I have in there should remove the sum column label; you say 'percent' but I don't have a percent there, so I'm not sure what you're running exactly.